# How the order you define commands in a class file changes the output?

Tags: macros, titles, document-classes

I'm working with a class file, trying to adjust it to my needs, and somewhere in the middle of it is defined a  function that writes the title of the paper. What I have is this:

```
\title{
\vspace{-30pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\HorRule
\\
\fontsize{35}{40}
\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}
\color{titlecolor}
\@TheTitle
\\
\end{flushleft}
}

\renewcommand{\title}[2]{\def\@TheTitle{#1}\def\@ShortTitle{#2}}
```

Let us begin with the last line of code. It defines a command `\title` with two arguments. When you call `\title` inside your `.tex` file what it does is to define two text replacements inside the `.cls` file. The `\@ShortTitle` will be used in the footer and `\@TheTitle` in the title. Now, going back to the first block of code, it calls a function `\title` which uses the value stored in `\@TheTitle`. My doubt is this: how can `\title` be called before it is defined (in the last line of the code)? And how can it use something that was not defined yet (the `\@TheTitle`)?

I tried to pass the line

```
\renewcommand{\title}[2]{\def\@TheTitle{#1}\def\@ShortTitle{#2}}
```

to the begining of the code but it simply does not work that way. What is going on?

Comment: Instead of `\title` define maybe `\createtitle` and then define a command to change the variables used within `\createtitle`: `\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{\def\@TheTitle{#1}\def\@ShortTitle{#2}}`. So, in your `tex` file you can use `\title{}{}` and `\createtitle`.

Comment: The way things are in the first block of code I have written above, the .tex file works without a problem. Your suggestion helps me to understand the code because the \title function is not called before it is defined anymore but the confusion remais with the \@TheTitle. How can \title use it as an argument before it is defined in the \newcommand bit?

Comment: The command is in the `cls` file. It will be executed only on `tex` file when you call it. In the `cls` you can change orders, no problem.

Comment: Note that macro expansion works lazily in LaTeX, i.e. all commands/macros defined by `\def` or `\newcommand` are only checked for existance at the time they are expanded. So in your case `\@TheTitle` can be used in the `\title` command even if it hasn't been defined so far. Problems only arise if `\title` is actually called in your code without `\@TheTitle` being defined at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Typical document classes only store the contents of `\title` inside a macro, let's say, `\@title`. The common procedure for this resembles

```
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
```

This allows users to specify `\title` inside the preamble (say) and only later issue `\maketitle` (within the `document` environment) to set the title. Whenever a call to `\title` is made, it can contain any "garbage" that may or may not exist - the problem (of undefined control sequences) will only realise itself when you actually set the title via `\maketitle`.

So, in your case, `\title` probably only stores it's contents inside `\@title` like the usual classes do, even though `\@TheTitle` is undefined at the time `\title` is called. When the user of your document class calls `\title`, it uses the redefined version of `\title` which sets the values of `\@TheTitle` and `\@ShortTitle`.

The reason for this ordering is probably to ensure that the default `\title` procedure (set via `\maketitle`) is still usable in the traditional sense. One issue may be that `\title` typically only takes a single argument, while the redefinition clearly requires two mandatory arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You have (again) only posted fragments, not a reproducible test case, so it is not possible to give a full answer but

> my doubt is this: how can `\title` be called before it is defined (in the last line of the code)?

the clue is in the last line

```
\renewcommand{\title}..
```

which is not a *definition* of `\title` but a *re*definition. This necessarily means that `\title` must already have been defined (presumably with a different definition) and it is that (unshown) definition that is used in the call to `\title` at the start of your fragment.

The previous, unshown, definition presumably defined `\title` with one argument not two, looking at the use here.

Unrelated to your question but the use of `\title`  containing negative spacing, low level font calls and unwanted space tokens is just *horrible* if you are learning latex, you really shouldn't be learning from code like this!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. All the tutorials I found on how to code a class file were really shallow. I don't know about the elegance of the code but this was the better example I could find, producing a good looking paper. I didn't posted the whole code because it's long and I think we might drift away from the point. What do you mean by low level font calls and unwanted space tokens?

Comment: @Gabu the use of `\title` at the start of your fragment has _9_ space tokens (from ends of lines) in its argument. that may or may not produce bad space in the output depending on its definition (which you have not shown) you should almost never have code such as `\fontsize{35}{40}
\usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}` within another macro, font setup should normally be document wide. If this document is using helvetica for titles that should have been set up elsewhere in the definition of the title page, not in the argument to `\title`.

Comment: @Gabu you are asking about the use of `\title` but did not post the definition of `\title` because you thought that may cause people to drift from the point of your question????

Comment: The only time \title appears in the whole file is in the fragment of code I provided . This class loads an article-like class (scrartcl), which I presume have \title defined in it. Sure, I didn't tell  what \HorRule does, it draws a horizontal line, but I didn't think it would matter for the question I have.

Comment: @Gabu so _now_ you have said what `\title` is defined as (scratcl's definition) the posted code in your question is completely meaningless without that information/

Comment: If negative spacing, low level font calls and unwanted space tokens is just horrible what should I do? What better options are available?

Comment: @Gabu I honestly can not guess why a class file has a _call_ to `\title` rather than a definition, that is clearly trying to typeset a title but typesetting is not allowed before `\begin{document}`  so just given your fragment of code out of context it is possible to say it is weird code but not possible to suggest anything better.